# Is Kafka streaming to Ignite running in Transactional mode ACID?

Tags: apache-kafka, ignite, acid

I have a distributed database in Apache Ignite and a Apache Kafka streaming service that streams data to the Ignite cluster. The Kafka streamer works as following

1. Create ignite node to find cluster
2. Start kafka streamer singleton as a service in the cluster
3. Shut down the ignite node

The Ignite cluster is in Transactional mode, however I am unsure if this guarantees ACID or only enables it. Could this streaming service to Ignite be considered ACID?

Here is the code for the kafka streamer:

```
public class IgniteKafkaStreamerService implements Service {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@IgniteInstanceResource
private Ignite ignite;
private KafkaStreamer<String, JSONObject> kafkaStreamer = new KafkaStreamer<>();
private IgniteLogger logger;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();

    TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();

    // Set Multicast group.
    //ipFinder.setMulticastGroup("228.10.10.157");

    // Set initial IP addresses.
    // Note that you can optionally specify a port or a port range.
    ipFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));

    spi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);

    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

    // Override default discovery SPI.
    cfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi);
    Ignite ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(cfg);

    // Deploy data streamer service on the server nodes.
    ClusterGroup forServers = ignite.cluster().forServers();
    IgniteKafkaStreamerService streamer = new IgniteKafkaStreamerService();
    ignite.services(forServers).deployClusterSingleton("KafkaService", streamer);
    ignite.close();
}


@Override
public void init(ServiceContext ctx) {
    logger = ignite.log();
    IgniteDataStreamer<String, JSONObject> stmr = ignite.dataStreamer("my_cache");
    stmr.allowOverwrite(true);
    stmr.autoFlushFrequency(1000);
    List<String> topics = new ArrayList<>();
    topics.add(0,"IoTData");

    kafkaStreamer.setIgnite(ignite);
    kafkaStreamer.setStreamer(stmr);
    kafkaStreamer.setThreads(4);
    kafkaStreamer.setTopic(topics);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "NiFi-consumer");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "192.168.1.242:9092");
    props.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put("group.id", "hello");
    kafkaStreamer.setConsumerConfig(props);
    kafkaStreamer.setSingleTupleExtractor(msg -> {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(msg.value().toString());
        String key = jsonObj.getString("id") + "," + new Date(msg.timestamp());
        JSONObject value = jsonObj.accumulate("date", new Date(msg.timestamp()));

        return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(key, value);

    });
}

@Override
public void execute(ServiceContext ctx) {
    kafkaStreamer.start();
    logger.info("KafkaStreamer started.");
}

@Override
public void cancel(ServiceContext ctx) {
    kafkaStreamer.stop();
    logger.info("KafkaStreamer stopped.");
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KafkaStreamer` uses `IgniteDataStreamer` implementations under the hood. `IgniteDataStreamer` isn't transactional by nature so there are no any transactional  guarantees.